Pyspark Structured Streaming
I've came across forEachBatch while reading about pyspark streaming. If we use forEachBatch to output the data in arbitrary sink then how does outputMode works with foreachBatch
e.g,
df_delta.writeStream.foreachBatch(data_upserter.upsert)
                     .outputMode("append")
                     .option("checkpointLocation", f"{self.checkpoint_base}/workout_bpm_summary")
                     .queryName("workout_bpm_summary_upsert_stream")

